# Use argument in handler function for Stencil component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, stenciljs

In an AngularJS project i use a custom Stencil component called rvn-chip to display teams with the option to remove the team.

This is done by the rvnRemove function inside the rvn-chip component, which then calls the remove function in the client. However, i need to pass the team in as an argument for the remove function, but i can't find any way to do it without getting a lot of errors.

I have tried a lot of different variations for sending the argument but none of them work, or they produce errors. Also, using just rvn-remove directly as an attribute does not work. Does anyone have any idea as to how to do this?

Here is the template:

```
  <rvn-chip
    text="{{ team.name }}"
    ng-repeat="team in $ctrl.teams"
    handlers="$ctrl.remove(team)">
  </rvn-chip>
```

And here is the controller:

```
angular.module('rvn-account')
    .component('userTeams', {
        bindings: {
            teams: '=',
            group: '=',
            handlers: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'account/components/user-teams/user-teams.html',
        controller: function (GroupTeam, authService) {
            const _this = this;

            GroupTeam.query({groupId: authService.userGroup().id}).$promise.then(function (teams) {
                _this.dbTeams = _.filter(teams, function (t) {
                    return t.group && t.group.id === _this.group.id
                });

            });

            _this.add = function (team) {
                _this.teams.push(team);
            };

            _this.remove = function (team) {
                console.log('remove team', team)
                _.remove(_this.teams, function (t) {
                    return t === team;
                })
            }
        }
    });
```